# Handle Status 304 response with AngularJS $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-http

If i have one API server then the API is send ajax data with JSON format :

```
{"status":304,"message":"Cannot delete data where PK is empty or > 1"}
```

how to AngularJS $http post call the status and message to alert bootbox?
here my AngularJS $http post

```
$http({
  method: "POST",
  url: apiUrl('disable_assethw'),
  data: {
    id: id
  },
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
  if(response.status == 304) {
    bootbox.alert("Something went error.." + response.data.message);
  } else {
    $scope.getAssetHW();
  }
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  bootbox.alert("Something went error.." + response.status);
});
```

thanks for advise.

Comment: you said its json and here you mention `{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}`

Comment: Unless you've altered the default `requestTransformer`, `{id: id}` is certainly not a valid payload for a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request

Comment: Wait, is that JSON at the top of your question the response payload from the server? If so, you want `if (response.data.status == 304)`

Comment: sorry for content type, i mean. how to call the `{"status":304,"message":"Cannot delete data where PK is empty or > 1"}` like **success** attribute on jquery. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: thanks for help, i found my solution, just call like u said @phil response.data.status / message. Then i clear cache my browser and gotcha, alert show. Thank all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing a POST request with JavaScript objects as data, use the AngularJS default content type (which is automatically set to `application/json`). The [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) also automatically encodes JavaScript objects as [JSON strings](http://www.json.org/).

Only response with status in the range 200-299 are processed by the success handler. Status outside the range are processed by the rejection handler:

```
$http({
  method: "POST",
  url: apiUrl('disable_assethw'),
  data: {
    id: id
  },
  headers: {
    ̶'̶C̶o̶n̶t̶e̶n̶t̶-̶T̶y̶p̶e̶'̶:̶ ̶'̶a̶p̶p̶l̶i̶c̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶/̶x̶-̶w̶w̶w̶-̶f̶o̶r̶m̶-̶u̶r̶l̶e̶n̶c̶o̶d̶e̶d̶'̶
  }
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
  ̶i̶f̶(̶r̶e̶s̶p̶o̶n̶s̶e̶.̶s̶t̶a̶t̶u̶s̶ ̶=̶=̶ ̶3̶0̶4̶)̶ ̶{̶
    ̶b̶o̶o̶t̶b̶o̶x̶.̶a̶l̶e̶r̶t̶(̶"̶S̶o̶m̶e̶t̶h̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶w̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶e̶r̶r̶o̶r̶.̶.̶"̶ ̶+̶ ̶r̶e̶s̶p̶o̶n̶s̶e̶.̶d̶a̶t̶a̶.̶m̶e̶s̶s̶a̶g̶e̶)̶;̶
   ̶}̶ ̶e̶l̶s̶e̶ ̶{̶
    $scope.getAssetHW();
  ̶}̶
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  //HANDLE 304 status HERE
  if(response.status == 304) {
    bootbox.alert("Something went error.." + response.data.message);
  } else {
    bootbox.alert("Something went error.." + response.status);
  };
});
```

From the Docs:

> A response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success status and will result in the success callback being called. Any response status code outside of that range is considered an error status and will result in the error callback being called. Also, status codes less than -1 are normalized to zero. -1 usually means the request was aborted.
>
> [— AngularJS $http Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

**Note:** A status of -1 usually indicates the browser rejected the request with a [CORS problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) that violates [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Answer (score 0):

you said it is **json** response and you used: **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** , which is wrong.

The best practice to handle rest/api call is:

Create 1 common/general function which is accessible in whole application which will manage your post api call(add api response to callback):

```
postAPICall(url, body, data) {
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    this.http
        .post(url,
            body, {
                headers: headers
            })
        .map(
            response => response.json())
        .subscribe(
            response => {
                data(response);
            },
            err => data(this.handleError(err)); //handle error here
        );
}
```

call this function wherever required(in component or service):

```
var yourJSONBody = {
    "param-1": "",
    "param-2": "",
    //....
    }
}

this.myCommonService.postAPICall("localhost:8080/app/", yourJSONBody, data => {
    if (data.status == "304") {
        //do stuff
        //this.msgs.push({severity: 'error', detail: data.message});
    }
    else {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

error handler function:

```
private handleError(error: any) {
    let description = 'There was an error: ' + error.status;
    let errors = {
        errorcode: error.status,
        errorstatus: error.statusText,
        errordescription: description
    };
    return errors;
}
```

Comment: Post me if you face any issue or error or if I am missing something.

Comment: Your answer uses the Angular 2+ `http` API. The question is for AngularJS  [$http Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)